# Layout in a QStandartItem for QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview, qlayout

I am searching for a way to have a QTreeView that contains hierarchical items which themselfs have a layout that is propperly drawn.

I tried to inherit from both QStandartItem and QWidget (to have a layout) but the second i set the layout on the widget part of this class the programm is shutting down when it tries to render.

```
class modPackItem(qtg.QStandardItem,qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,txt:str='',image_path:str='./assets/defaultModPack.jpg'):
        super().__init__()
    
        fnt = qtg.QFont('Calibri',12)
        fnt.setBold(True)
    
        self.setEditable(False)
        self.setForeground(qtg.QColor(0,0,0))
        self.setFont(fnt)
        self.setText(txt)
        self.horLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horLayout.addWidget(qtw.QLabel("test"))
        #self.setLayout(self.horLayout) #this breaks the rendering
            
        modPack_image = qtg.QImage(image_path)        
        self.setData(modPack_image.scaled(64,64,qtc.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding),qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole)
```

Is there a possible way to have all items in the QTreeView contain layouts (For example with multiple texts[description,tag-words,etc]).

[image: Example TreeView containing the desired custom item with layout]

Note: I also considered switching to a simple List of widgets which have children containing the hierarchical items. But that would increase complexity of my app-structure a lot and therefore i would like to avoid that.

Edit: To clearify what i want to do:
I want to build a mod(pack) manager in the style of the technic-launcher for minecraft mods but instead for any kind of game in any kind of infrastructure(steam, local instal,etc). By clicking different buttons i add new "modpacks" or "mods" (optimally custom QStandartItem with Layout for all the data) in an hierarchical fashion (therefore treeview). Adding the items and the steam-subsrciption or filecopy logic is no problem but i would like to see all infos (Name,descritpion, custom tags) on the overview (like in the example pic). I know i could bind the QStandartItem selection method to a new popup showing all infos but that would be inconvinient.

Edit2: On terms of implementation i just add the QStandartItem-object as an additional row to the root-node before setting the model. I allready tested adding new objects to the rootnode by clicking on a button and that worked fine. Just setting the layout in the object crashes the application at start.

```
class SteamModManager_Dialog(qtw.QDialog):
window: Ui_SteamModManagerFrame
treeModel: qtg.QStandardItemModel
rootNode: qtg.QStandardItem


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.window = Ui_SteamModManagerFrame()
    self.window.setupUi(self)

    self.window.label_footer.setText("")
    
    self.treeModel = qtg.QStandardItemModel()
    self.rootNode = self.treeModel.invisibleRootItem()
    
    modPack = modPackItem('Dont Starve Together')
    testMod = modItem("TestMod")
    
    modPack.appendRow(testMod)     
    
    self.rootNode.appendRow(modPack)   
    
    self.window.tView_modPacks.setModel(self.treeModel)
    self.window.tView_modPacks.expandAll()
```

Comment: maybe you can use stylesheets: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/stylesheet-examples.html

Comment: i had a quick try on it but like with setLayout, the second i set the stylesheet to "QLineEdit { background-color: yellow }" (for example) the app collapses on rendering.

Comment: have you tried `.setLayout()` on the object?

Comment: It's not really clear how you're using that class, and using such double inheritance seems quite odd, since you should not directly associate a QStandardItem with a widget (the item could be destroyed by the model). You should use [`setIndexWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) instead.

Comment: @Aking what do you mean by using .setLayout on the object? Afaik .setLayout is called by the widget itself to set its layout and to "register" the layout to the rendering framework

Comment: @musicamante as an explainer to the usage i edited the original text

Comment: @musicamente thanks for the advice on the .setIndexWidget function. I will later test to do it with a layout or to chain multiple lines together.

Comment: @4lexKidd sorry, but we are not really interested in the purpose of your program, as knowing it doesn't change the technical aspects of the question, nor its answers. What we need to know is what you *programmatically* do, so (as already asked) *how* you're using that class in the rest of the program.

Comment: @musicamante oh my bad, english is not my mother tongue. I edited the question to reflect my implementation.

Comment: @4lexKidd Sorry, I finally had time to read your question more carefully. And I can repeat you what said since my first comment: inheriting from QStandardItem and QWidget is pointless (and wrong, since they are completely different classes that would take absolutely no benefit from their "merge"). You either use a custom QWidget subclass along with `setIndexWidget()` or you use a custom item delegate. In the second case, you can still use a custom subclass (for complex layouts), or just override the methods you need, starting with [`paint()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint).

Comment: @4lexKidd please take the inheritance remark very seriously. Multiple inheritance allows to merge aspects of two or more "templates" into a single one that takes benefits from them, while sharing common concepts. You can create a subclass that inherits from a couch and a bed and get a sofa-bed. Inheriting from QStandardItem and QWidget is almost like inheriting from a paper sheet and a table: yes, you could write some text on both of them, but you can't have a notebook made of tables, nor you'd have serve a dinner on your homework.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the advice. I will test both concepts and post the best or most comfortable solution here when i made it work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the behalf of @musicamente here the solution that worked out for me:

I created a widget in the designer (as usual, not posting the full ui code here).

Then i implemented the following code into the Dialog:

```
self.treeModel = qtg.QStandardItemModel()
self.rootNode = self.treeModel.invisibleRootItem()
    
modPack = modPackItem('Dont Starve Together')
testMod = modItem("TestMod")
   
modPack.appendRow(testMod)     
    
self.rootNode.appendRow(modPack)           
    
self.window.tView_modPacks.setModel(self.treeModel)
self.window.tView_modPacks.expandAll()
    
modPackWidget = qtw.QWidget()
ui = Ui_modPackWidget()
ui.setupUi(modPackWidget)
    
self.window.tView_modPacks.setIndexWidget(self.treeModel.index(0,0),modPackWidget)
```

This code resulted setting the custom widget to the treeview item. Here the final look:
[image: Final Result TreeView Item with corresponding Widget containing a Layout]